# Mongoose Model.schema.path() returns an unexpected object

Tags: node.js, mongoose, enums, model, schema

I'm trying to get the enum values for a `language` property from an `User` mongoose model

In the past I've done it like this:

`User.schema.path('languages').enumValues`

But for some reason the `path` property doesn't return what I expected. Instead it returns this:

```
SchemaArray {
  schemaOptions: {
    timestamps: true,
    toJSON: { virtuals: true, transform: [Function: transform] },
    typePojoToMixed: true,
    typeKey: 'type',
    id: true,
    noVirtualId: false,
    _id: true,
    noId: false,
    validateBeforeSave: true,
    read: null,
    shardKey: null,
    autoIndex: null,
    minimize: true,
    discriminatorKey: '__t',
    optimisticConcurrency: false,
    versionKey: '__v',
    capped: false,
    bufferCommands: true,
    strictQuery: false,
    strict: true,
    pluralization: true
  },
  casterConstructor: [Function: SchemaString] {
    schemaName: 'String',
    defaultOptions: {},
    _cast: [Function: castString],
    cast: [Function: cast],
    get: [Function (anonymous)],
    set: [Function: set],
    _checkRequired: [Function (anonymous)],
    checkRequired: [Function (anonymous)]
  },
  caster: SchemaString {
    enumValues: [
      'spanish', 'english',
      'french',  'german',
      'chinese', 'japanese',
      'hindi',   'bengali',
      'korean',  'italian',
      'turkish', 'portuguese',
      'arabic'
    ],
    regExp: null,
    path: 'languages',
    instance: 'String',
    validators: [ [Object] ],
    getters: [],
    setters: [],
    options: SchemaStringOptions {},
    _index: null,
    enumValidator: [Function (anonymous)],
    _arrayPath: 'languages.$',
    [Symbol(mongoose#schemaType)]: true
  },
  '$embeddedSchemaType': SchemaString {
    enumValues: [
      'spanish', 'english',
      'french',  'german',
      'chinese', 'japanese',
      'hindi',   'bengali',
      'korean',  'italian',
      'turkish', 'portuguese',
      'arabic'
    ],
    regExp: null,
    path: 'languages',
    instance: 'String',
    validators: [ [Object] ],
    getters: [],
    setters: [],
    options: SchemaStringOptions {},
    _index: null,
    enumValidator: [Function (anonymous)],
    _arrayPath: 'languages.$',
    [Symbol(mongoose#schemaType)]: true
  },
  '$isMongooseArray': true,
  path: 'languages',
  instance: 'Array',
  validators: [],
  getters: [],
  setters: [],
  options: SchemaArrayOptions {
    type: [ [Function: String] ],
    enum: [
      'spanish', 'english',
      'french',  'german',
      'chinese', 'japanese',
      'hindi',   'bengali',
      'korean',  'italian',
      'turkish', 'portuguese',
      'arabic'
    ]
  },
  _index: null,
  defaultValue: [Function: defaultFn] { '$runBeforeSetters': true },
  [Symbol(mongoose#schemaType)]: true
}
```

It seems to the that is returning this path as an independent Schema, instead as as a property which is what it is. Any clue as to why?